# Late 1980s-1990s book about a kid trapped in a video game found on his front porch

Tags: story-identification

A good friend of mine is looking for a copy of a book he read when he was a kid, and I want to help so I figured I would ask you guys and see if anyone is familiar.

From what I understand, the book is from the late 80's or early 90's, and is about a kid who gets home from school and finds a new video game sitting on his front porch. He starts the game up and gets sucked into the game. He has to beat the game to get home.

My friend described the cover art saying that it is a young man brandishing a green sword and is fighting a two headed demon. He said the boy may be on a staircase or raised dais surrounded by flames. If this rings a bell for anyone let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113936/31178

Answer (score 9):

Based on the description of the cover, I was thinking it was [Killobyte](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441444253) by Piers Anthony. The themes (trapped in a computer game) are similar but there's no porch and no teens.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

#### *[The Seventh Crystal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/515670.The_Seventh_Crystal)* by Gary Paulsen

[image: Book Cover - *The Seventh Crystal*]

> Each day at 3 P.M., Chris Masters faces two great challenges. First, he races home, trying to avoid the school bullies who have made a career out of beating him up. Then, once he's safely home, he takes on another opponet [sic]--a computer game called The Seventh Crystal. Soon Chris is obsessed with the game--and finds he has something much bigger than bullies to worry about.

Comment: Could you explain which aspects of this work fit the question description?

Comment: The description fits exactly, down to the last detail. I can't attach an image from my phone, but if you search for the book I suggested, the cover is identical to the given description. The plot is as well. It was a favorite book of mine from childhood.

Comment: Great! Maybe you can add a brief plot summary later?

Answer (score 6):

I'm remembering I read this in the 80s...I can't find the cover I remember, but it sounds a bit like [The Battle of Zorn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/412750.The_Battle_of_Zorn) to me.

[image: Book cover]

A review:

> I can't remember much about this title except that it is about a kid who plays a video game and gets transported into the video game world and has to fight the wars going on therein... I lost this book a very long time ago, but it was the best book I ever picked up from a visit from Scholastic Book Fair

Answer (score 5):

[*Space Demons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Demons) by Gillian Rubenstein

> The main four characters in the book are Andrew Hayford, Ben Challis, Elaine Taylor and Mario Ferrone. The plot starts when Andrew's dad brings him an exciting prototype video game from Japan. Andrew, who is a video game enthusiast, shows it to his best friend Ben Challis, who agrees to play the game with him. Later, two other players are introduced to the game: Mario Ferrone and Elaine Taylor. It is later revealed that it is possible to get transported into the game by means of a special gun, which only works when a strong beam of hate is directed at someone. Later on, the four get trapped inside the game and gradually work out the only way to escape and thus win the game is if they conquer their hate.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you provided some corroborative evidence with your answer.  As it is, this doesn't really help identify your suggestion as the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found your answer already, but I was trying to find a similar book and this post came up.

The book I was looking for was called [*Space Demons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Demons).

[image: Space Demons cover]

And a sequel called *Skymaze*.

Also just realized the author, [Gillian Rubenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillian_Rubinstein), wrote under another name, Lian Hearn.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good first answer. See if you can add what specific details from your suggestion match that of the OP. Also, stop by our [tour] and [help] to get familiar with the site.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that someone has already suggested this answer.  You should only post a duplicate answer if you're going to take the time to make a more complete answer that more specifically addresses the points in the question, for example by providing quotes from the book.  Note that this cover does not match the one described in the question at all.

Answer (score -1):

The book is rodomonte's revenge by Gary paulsen

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide a bit more info on the book, and explain why you think it might be the book the OP was looking for, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. See the previous answers for reference.