# Book about a boy getting stuck in a video game, one-eyed monkey involved

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book when I was a kid so I only remember a few details, but I really want to find it.

It was about a kid who I'm fairly certain gets trapped in his video game because there's one part I remember very clearly about him being in a temple (I think it was filling with a black liquid? There was some kind of timer) and it was a level he had never been able to beat because he couldn't figure it out. I'm pretty sure the Mayan calendar was somehow involved.
I also know there was something up with monkeys. Specifically, I seem to remember a one eyed monkey being important. (I recall something about that monkey appearing in a dream?)

EDIT: I'm not so great with time, but I definitely read it before 2013. I'd guess I read it between 2009-2013. Again my ability to pinpoint time frames is nonexistent, but I hope this helps!

EDIT 2: I was kindly directed towards a list of things to add, so here are all the questions I can answer.

-I recall it being a complete novel and I don't believe there was a sequel

-There's an extremely high chance I got it from the YA section in a barnes and nobles

-It was in English

-I believe the setting was in South America (that's where the game was set) and there is time spent in a rainforest

-I remember very clearly the character freaking out in the temple because if he failed again, as he always had, he wouldn't ever be able to try again because it wasn't a video game anymore.

-I'm fairly certain the main character was an American adolescent boy

-The scene I keep mentioning at the temple is why it's memorable for me. The internal panic was something that struck me

-The book wasn't particularly old, I bought it around the time I read it.

-The one eyed monkey was also very memorable. I think the mc had a dream about the monkey before he ended up in the game, and it was one of the first things he encountered in the game

Comment: Could you please tell us how long ago were you a kid ? What is obvious to you sometimes not so obvious to others :).
Also have a look here, maybe one of the answers is the book you are looking for : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78893/looking-for-a-book-about-a-kid-trapped-in-a-video-game

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Cԃաԃ I have looked through that thread, sadly it wasn't there. I edited the post for you too. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Valorum Thank you! I added every question I could recall an answer to. I appreciate the guidance, hope the question is better now!

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/13547332-ack-ack-macaque has the video game world being partly real, and the one-eyed monkey (cigar-chomping RAF ace pilot!), but the other bits don't match.