# Book about a boy who gets transported into a fantasy video game on a floppy disc

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read a book back in '95 and I can't remember the title. It's about a boy who gets a new video game on a floppy disc and tries to play. He is transported inside the game and the adventure begins.

I remember the cover being full of fantasy creatures like elves, dwarves, fairies, orcs, dragons (I do remember a dragon on the cover), etc (not sure if all of these are on the cover, but I added them for reference). I believe the cover had a boy at the bottom right, a road up the center, mythical creatures on each side of the road and a castle at the top of the road.

I would love for my son to read it. I know that it's **not** *"Space Demons"*.

Comment: possibles: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78893/looking-for-a-book-about-a-kid-trapped-in-a-video-game/154951#154951, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32518/kid-gets-sucked-into-a-video-game-or-tv-show/113936#113936, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124756/looking-for-90s-2000s-teen-fantasy-book-about-kids-pulled-into-an-rpg/124767#124767

Comment: And (like Tacroy suggested in one of those questions) you may want to look through  TVTROPES WARNING http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrappedInTVLand in case you find your book. It doesn't have too many examples, you should be able to check them.

Comment: I believe the cover had a boy at the bottom right, a road up the center, mythical creatures on each side of the road and a castle at the top of the road. Hope this helps someone identify the book

Comment: Which language? I have an idea, but it is originally a German one: Schattenjagd by Wolfgang Hohlbein, but it was not translated into English

Answer (score 3):

***[Demons Don't Dream](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/15453.Demons_Don_t_Dream)*** (1992) by Piers Anthony.

[image: Cover of "Demons Don't Dream" by Piers Anthony. The cover shows a young girl holding a dog on the bottom right, with a demon in fancy dress with glasses writing in a book in the center. A castle fills the background.]

It's the 16th book in the *[Xanth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth)* series.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/15453.Demons_Don_t_Dream):

> Beloved by millions of readers around the world, Piers Anthony's Xanth novels are among the most popular fantasy adventures ever published. *Demons Don't Dream* begins a thrilling new Xanth sequence, as a pair of young adventurers play for the highest stakes of all: the future of Xanth--and of Earth as well!
>
> Drawn into Xanth by a harmless-looking computer game, two young people find themselves competing for a precious prize: Dug, who is beguiled by a beautiful serpent-princess, and Kim, who discovers her favorite fantasy realm has suddenly become frighteningly real.
>
> In a desperate race against time, Dug and Kim battle their way across the wondrous, perilous land of Xanth, testing their courage against dozens of fearsome obstacles (and their wits against a host of outrageous puns!) But when treachery, danger, and deceit place Xanth itself in peril, Dug and Kim learn that some things are more important than winning or losing.
>
> A breathtaking, madcap quest filled with fearsome monsters and far-fetched fun, Demons Don't Dream is vintage Xanth, an unforgettable escapade from fantasy's most imaginative storyteller.